# jQuery datatables Fix Header Not Adjusting

Tags: datatables, fixheadertable

I have a table that´s using Fix Header without initializing it as a DataTable because I need to use rowspan on the body. The fix header initialize ok but whenever another jQuery event like collapse on the page occurs, the fix header looses its position and won't came back unless I scroll the page with the mouse.

I tried to use the `fixHeader.fnUpdate();`
but it didn't work for me.

Any ideas?

I leave you the link to the live example.

http://jsfiddle.net/varini_matias/Qd5ju/9/

http://jsfiddle.net/varini_matias/Qd5ju/7/embedded/result/

(click on the message that says "Click here to see the problem")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to solve it, although i do not think is the best one.

I use the `$('.fixedHeader').remove();` to remove the fixHeader whenever the slideUp or slideDown occurs and on the complete function I create again the fixHeader.

Comment: am also facing same issue.fixed header position still in absolute position only when scrolling how to resolve this. could you please provide updated fiddle ?